# What are some ideas for how to add feedback to a Checkbox input?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, feedback, user-feedback

The normal use of a Checkbox is fairly straightforward. You click the box and a check appears in the box. You click again to remove the check.

I'm looking for a way to add feedback to the clicking of the box. My current idea is that you would have to click and hold down on the Checkbox and a progress bar would pop up and begin filling up. Then the item would only be checked after holding down for a given period of time, giving a sense of completion.

Sorry if this question is a bit vague, but I'm looking for not only implementation advice, but also any other ideas of how to create a sense of completion and feedback from clicking in general.

I know we're not exactly using DualShock controllers to do our clicking on the web (so haptic feedback is probably impossible), but I'm just looking to experiment with ways that we could simulate something similar.

Comment: As you state: a check appears in the box after clicking it - how is that not feedback?

Comment: I think he wants to add a little pizaz to the user experience.  Some guy called Steve Jobs also thinks this is a good idea :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use highlight to let the user know they clicked something or something happened

```
$foo.effect('highlight',{'color':'cyan'},300);
```

using jquery ui effects

Comment: This is a great suggestion. Nothing too flashy, but still some added feedback: http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/default.html

Answer (score 0):

Page explodes in fireworks everytime you click something:

```
$('*').click().createFirework(100,200,8,7,null,null,null,null,false,true);
```

Using [Fireworks.js](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/fireworks/).